# How to make user generated core data entities options in a UIPickerview

Tags: swift, core-data, uipickerview

So I'm working on a calculator app and I've hit a wall when it comes to my UIPickerView and my core data. I currently have it set up so the user can save settings using a core-data entity. This also pushes the name attribute of the entity to an array. The UIPickerView then uses the names in the array to auto-populates fields using the selected core-data entity. However, the array I'm currently using does not persist after closing the app. I'm looking for a way to push the name attributes to an array in such a way that the array stores the data after restarting the app. That way the UIPickerView can access the names after restart.

Here's the way I'm currently doing things.

```
var pickerOptions = ["none"]

...

@IBAction func saveSettings (_ sender: Any){
...code to save settings...
coreDataManager.shared.createSetting(power: power, name:name)

pickerOptions.append(name)
}

func numberOfcomponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView)-> Int {
return 1}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component:Int) ->Int{
return pickerOptions.count}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
return pickerOptions[row]}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row:Int, inComponent component: Int){
let setting = coreDataManager.shared.fetchSetting(withName: pickerOptions[row])
...code for auto-populating...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured it out. I wrote a function in my core data handler to dump all my entities into an array. Then it loops through the array pulling out all the .name attributes. It then returns that array. Then in my view controller I call the function and set it equal to a variable. I then use that variable for my UIPickerView array. Code solution below.

```
//function to generate array from core data. This happens in my coreDataManager file.

func fetchSettingName() ->[String] {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        var settingOptions = ["none"]
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Settings>(entityName: "Settings")
        do{
            let settings = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

            for setting in settings{
                settingOptions.append("\(setting.name!)")
            }
            return settingOptions
        }catch let fetchError {
            print("Failed to fetch companies: \(fetchError)")
        }
        return [""]

//How I implemented it into my UIPickerView.This happens in my view controller

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
//calls an array out of core data. The array contains all the title properties for all setting entities

        let settingOptions = coreDataManager.shared.fetchPresetsName()
        return settingOptions.count
```